# Need help to insert some text to my c++ file

Tags: bash

I want to insert some text to my c++ file after certain line ( pattern ). The following is my file structure.

```
38 #include "stdlib.h"
39 #include "string.h"
40 #include "malloc.h"
41 

  ...

324 void DMProcMon::threadManagerMonitorThread(DMProcMon* dmProcMon)
325 {

    ...

338 while (dmState == DVProcMon::Active &&
339         DmManService::getDCMRestartingFlag() == 0){
340     try{

342         setupTimerVerification(dmProcMon);
343         setupSignalVerification(dmProcMon);
344
    ....

360 }
```

I want to add code coverage macros using gcov. So basically what I need to achieve is

1. Add below text after all the #include statements.

   ```
   45 #ifdef GCOV
   46 extern "C"
   47 void _gcov_flush();
   48 #endif
   ```
2. Add the below text after the while statement in the threadManagerMonitorThread function

   ```
   #ifdef GCOV
   _gcov_flush();
   #endif
   ```

So final code will loos like as below.

```
38 #include "stdlib.h"
39 #include "string.h"
40 #include "malloc.h"
41 

45 #ifdef GCOV
46 _gcov_flush();
47 #endif

  ...


324 void DMProcMon::threadManagerMonitorThread(DMProcMon* dmProcMon)
325 {

    ...

338 while (dmState == DVProcMon::Active &&
339         DmManService::getDCMRestartingFlag() == 0){
340     try{

342 #ifdef GCOV
343 _gcov_flush();
344 #endif

346         setupTimerVerification(dmProcMon);
347         setupSignalVerification(dmProcMon);
348
    ....

360 }
```

What is the best way to do this. I would like to do this with either bash or pythyon.

Thanks
~S

Comment: You may want to learn how to use `ed` see [its documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)

Comment: `Awk` should be the right tool, it addresses rows by regular expressions and provides a powerful language for text editing.

Comment: Your first `ifdef` section is not included in your final code. And second section is not after a `while`, it's after a `try`. In what way does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `sed` to insert a line after/before a line containing a certain pattern. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695086/2749648.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183516/2749648) is the explanation on how to insert a line after a block of code (this will help you with the `#include` block) but i am not sure on how to fix the `while` statement. If while statement is on a single line, it would be easy, but that is hard to guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but in my case as this is a C++ file I want to insert the lines inside the particular function scope and inside the while statement and inside try statement. So it is not a very straight forward substitution or insertion.